# NSSortDescriptor not sorting - Core Data

Tags: ios, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of 10 items and want to sort based on a `NSNumber` value. The objects in this array are Core Data objects. The below is the code I have written to fetch a sorted array.

The problem is that the sort works only for two objects and not all. What have I done wrong?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"OrderList" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"orderNumber" ascending:YES]; //selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

orderNumArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];    
orderList = [orderNumArray copy];
[self.orderTable reloadData];
```

> // before sorting
>
> 1005 1004 1002 1001 1003
>
> // after sorting
>
> 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005
>
> // while table loading
>
> 1004 1005 1002 1001 1003

// loading table

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *ordersCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


if (ordersCell==nil) {
    ordersCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

}
 ordersCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

 OrderList *orderListNew1 = [orderList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  // orderListNew1.orderNumber is used in the UILabel. 


 return ordersCell;

}
```

Comment: Is the result always sorted the same? Is `orderNumber` transient? are you logging to check the result (show the log).

Comment: What are the values for orderNumber, and in with order are they being returned?

Comment: Post NSLog of `orderNumArray`, and your `-tableview:cellForRowatIndexPath:` method. If `orderNumArray` is corrent, the you incorrectly reuse the cells.

Comment: Please check the edit.. i have posted the code

Comment: @wain - yes.. its always getting sorted like that... No "orderNumber" is not transient...

Comment: How do you know the order before sort if the sort is part of the fetch? And if the fetch returns good sorted results, what do you do between there and the table view?

Comment: i dont do anything between that.. Even if the sort is just on the array and not a part of fetch, its doing the same thing... I tried setting break points .. But no result..